# ionic 3 white screen Google map

Tags: google-maps, ionic-framework, ionic3

i tried to show a google map in my ionic 3 project . but when i type

> ionic serve

it only shows a grey screen where the map should be without no error in the console .

here is my code :

**home.ts***

```
import { Component , ViewChild,ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController , Platform } from 'ionic-angular';
declare var google: any;
@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {
  @ViewChild("map") mapRef :ElementRef ;
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public platform :Platform) {
    platform.ready().then(() => {
      this.showMap();
    });   
  }
  showMap(){
    const location = new google.maps.LatLng(30.414047, -9.580157);

    const option ={
      center :location ,
      zoom : 15  ,
     streetViewControl : false ,
     mapTypeId :'roadMap'
    } ;
  const map =new google.maps.Map(this.mapRef.nativeElement ,option ) ;
this.addMarker(location, map);

  }
  addMarker(position , map){
return new google.maps.Marker({
  position ,
  map
}) ;
  }}
```

***home.html***

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar color="primary">
    <ion-title>
      Google maps 
    </ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>
  <div #map id="map"></div>
</ion-content>
```

***home.sccs***

```
page-home {
#map {
        height: 100%;
    }
}
```

plus i added this :

```
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCIJTDtdHB4s381xQEwzVsfdBxbr9kWkJk" async defer></script>
```

***Update : ***
when i commented this line :

```
 showMap(){
    // streetViewControl : false ,
     //mapTypeId :'roadMap'
    } ;
```

the map shows up .i dont know why .

Comment: Where did you add the google maps script tag ?

Comment: @JorgeMejia in my index.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is plnkr with an example, how can you initialize your google maps.

First you have to init your map in the ionViewDidLoad() also your map container need to hve a width :100% and height:100%;

```
ionViewDidLoad() {
    this.initMap();
  }

initMap(){
    //const location = new google.maps.LatLng(20.623736, -87.073395);
    let myLatLng = {lat: 20.623736, lng: -87.073395};
    console.log(location);
    const option ={
         center :myLatLng ,
         zoom : 15  ,
         //streetViewControl : false ,
         //mapTypeId :'roadMap'
    } ;
    //console.log(this.mapElement)
    const map = new google.maps.Map(this.mapElement.nativeElement ,option ) ;
    this.addMarker(myLatLng, map);
  }
```

This because you are not using the native plugin. You need to whait until your page where loaded.

An other observation is in your function addMarker you only pass the position and map values you have to put the key, val params.

```
addMarker(position , map){
     return new google.maps.Marker({
        position: position,
        map: map,
        title: 'Hello World!'
      });
   }
```

This is a full example I made for you.

https://plnkr.co/edit/pQqJoJrqfUVfAgiv1HA9?p=preview

Comment: Thaaanks alot Sir !  I really appreciate  the effort you put in it just to help me .It woooooorks now :)

Comment: If you want a better experience with maps I recomed yo to use the native plugin, with this plugin you can have all the touch gestures :) https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/google-maps/

Comment: Thanks Sir ! i will .

Answer (score 1):

I don't know much about iconic framework.
But your script on google maps API does not have callback and it loads async.
Why not try putting callback in calling the script.

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=showMap" async defer></script>
```

Comment: Thanks alot ! i added it .

Answer (score 0):

The problem could be down to you calling it within the `constructor`. Try putting the constructor code inside `ngAfterViewInit()` method instead.

Comment: still the same problem .here is how  my page look : https://ibb.co/b51BrH